# TextView inside Toolbar null with Butterknife

Tags: android, android-toolbar, butterknife

I am not asking for the solution but want to know why `TextView` inside Toolbar is returned null ?
I am using Butterknife inside a fragment.

```
@BindView(R2.id.toolbarTitle)
    TextView toolbarTitle;
```

Here's my layout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_widget"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorAccent"
                app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
                >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:gravity="center">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/toolbarTitle"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:textColor="#ffffff"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size18"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Here's my logcat:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
```

Okay here's the code as requested:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_nav_bookmark_trend_my_quote, container, false);
        toolbarTitle.setText(getString(R.string.bookmarks));
        accessToken = AppSharedPreferences.getsharedprefInstance(getContext()).getStringValue(AppSharedPreferences.KEY_USER_TOKEN);
        mUnbinder = ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
        mLinearLayout = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLinearLayout);


        DrawerLayout drawer = ((EpicSwiperActivity) getActivity()).drawerLayout;
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                getActivity(), drawer, mToolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        addRecyclerViewScrollState(mRecyclerView);
        return view;
}
```

Comment: Post code for fragment where are you using textview

Comment: what is that R2 mean ???

Comment: Use: `toolbarTitle.setText(R.string.your_title);`

Comment: Please go through the Butterknife docs. @SatanPandeya

Comment: Ok ok. I do use butterknife but never find that before. The inner `LinearLayout` seems unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

Just try this

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(toolbar_widget);
getActivity().setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

TextView tvTitle = (TextView) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.toolbarTitle);
tvTitle.setText(title);
```

By `ButterKnife` just try this

```
TextView textView = ButterKnife.findById(toolbar, R.id.toolbarTitle);
```

**{{ EDIT }}**

`toolbar.xml`

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:background="?attr/colorAccent"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_widget"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <LinearLayout
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/toolbarTitle"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size18"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>
 </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

`fragmentlayout.xml`

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <include
       android:id="@+id/toolbar_widget"
       layout="@layout/toolbar"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

in your `Java` file

```
View toolbarView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.toolbar,null);
TextView textView = ButterKnife.findById(toolbarView, R.id.toolbarTitle);
```

Comment: Since we cannot use setSupportActionBar(toolbar), I have used         `((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
&         ((MyActivity)getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);`  but it didn't work.

Comment: Ok I thought you are calling in your activity I will edit it.

Comment: But it didn't work. Only thing that worked was without using Butterknife and referring `toolbar.findViewById(R.id.toolbarTitle)`.

Comment: I had edited my answer just check and try hope it works

Comment: Yes,I know it will work but can you tell me why do we need to refer those separately, I mean why `TextView` inside `Toolbar` can't be referred to directly ? We're keeping them under the same root layout though.

Comment: Also why can't we use @BindView(R2.id.toolbarTitle) TextView toolbarTitle directly ?

Comment: you can not bind directly because `toolbar` inflates its own view so that `Butterknife` allow only one view to be binded

Comment: Yes, I see that. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Debdeep I have updated my answer to work with your scenario. Just try it works or not?

Comment: Yes, I have tried it already. Still thinking why would `Toolbar` inflate its own layout :) .Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Did you set your `toolbar` as an `ActionBar` properly otherwise do it as:

```
ToolBar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_widget);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Answer (score 0):

Cross-refer your TextView ID with the ID you used on `@BindView`.

And since you are using fragment make sure you pass in th root view of the fragment along with context when you call `ButterKnife.bind(this, rootView);`

e.g.

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fancy_fragment, container, false);
    ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
```